# Filtering recyclerview data that has been added today

Tags: java

i have a recyclerview that  shows a list of patients , the list has an item each item holds the patient informations like name, lastname, date of birth and sexe, the user can add new patients i want to differenctiate between the old patients and the patients that has been added today how to do that , i want  when i click on "today" button only the patients added today appear and when clicking on "all" button the total list appear. (My data are retreived from firebase realtime database)

i tried when adding a new patient , the date and time of when he has been added get stored in a field in the database .